# Pushing specifically formatted items to an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have to make this structure of objects:

```
var wps = [{ location: point1 }, { location: point2 }, {location: point4}];
```

from a JavaScript for loop, where I use:

```
for( i = 0; i < infos.positionLogs.length; i++) {
    point = new google.maps.LatLng(infos.positionLogs[i].coordinate.latitude,infos.positionLogs[i].coordinate.longitude);
    wps.push( {
        location: point
    } );
}
```

But when I log it to the console it's not exactly what I want.. what could be the problem?
Log:

```
Object {location: pf}
```

By dropdowned:

```
location: pf
A: 47.94881
F: 22.799589999999966
```

Just the same as with manual pushin :/
I use it for google maps getDirection and directionRenders, but gives me errors all the time. Interesting that error is changing, late messages are just saying GET error by:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/DirectionsService.Route?4b0&5m4&1m3…900660000000016&6e0&12shu-HU&100b0&102b0&callback=_xdc_._edv3g8&token=4544
```

Comment: Are you sure that `infos.positionLogs.length` is more than 1 ?

Comment: Yes, it gets back the 390 items which is correct.

Comment: Can you post some more code ? Like what is the initial value of `wps` ? What are the google services you are using to get `infos` ? At least some sample data :)

Comment: wps initially is empty, i get infos just with .ajax from a json, where are hundreds of thousands of datas storen. The google map generating is as usual, some styling, some div to get as container and place everything inside -all is working, except the line drawing. But for example the first 2 elements of the wps if i generate it with my push are: `Object {location: pf}
location: pf
A: 47.94881
F: 22.799589999999966
__proto__: pf
__proto__: Object` and `Object {location: pf}
location: pf
A: 47.949070000000006
F: 22.797890000000052
__proto__: pf
__proto__: Object`

Comment: this is interesting, can you log your wps value before the loop, inside the loop, and after the loop? see what is going on there.

Comment: sure... added console.log with speakable strings `[]`, then `Object0: Object1:.... Objectlength: 390`, then `Object0: Object1:.... Objectlength: 390` itemcount is correct but DirectionService is just gives me GET error... btw here is an example from in the loop: `0: Object
location: pf
A: 47.94881
F: 22.799589999999966` and after the loop: `0: Object
location: pf
A: 47.94881
F: 22.799589999999966` I tried the typeof which is also say the two result is basically the same. In loop: `type of: object`, and after: `type of: object`

Answer (score 0):

Well... after some headache.. I figured out. The problem is that with DirectionService we can only use 25 pois (10 in free), so with these 390 pois it get the response of `MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED`. Now I remade the whole thing with Polylines, maybe it could handle the route, regardless to its long... Hope it'll help for someone who get the same problem :)